# Software to keep track of an aging parent living alone

Tags: iphone-app, elderly

My mother lives alone and we are concerned about how I will know if something has happened to her if I haven't talked to her for a few days. Our idea was to have her e-mail/text every couple days. These ideas, however, still seem to have some friction that make them less than ideal. She uses a computer daily and has the latest iPhone. Is there software (or IFTTT recipe) that the two of us can use that will alert me if she has been idle for some period of time? Something such as an alert if her phone doesn't move or she doesn't log into Facebook for a day?

To clarify, I live close to my mother and visit often. The intent of this question is to close the 24-hr gap in case of some medical emergency.

Answer (score 2):

I know, this site is about ***Software*** Recommendations. But trying to NOT use any software at all, or only if all other means fail, would be way more effective to "check" how she's doing ... Think of ways to have human interactions, visit her, invite her, encourage her to continue to be active in whatever she likes.

Here are some IFTTT-like-recipes:

- **If** you have time **Then** go visit her **Else** free up some time for it anyway (no software / device will ever beat her "user experience").
- **If** you realize it has been too long you talked to her **Then** call / eMail / SMS here (I bet you have plenty of softwares / devices you can think of that you can use for that).
- **If** you have things delivered to her that she doesn't expect **Then** expect unexpected receipt confirmations.